# Friedman equation with non-negligible neutrino masses

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

I have heard that the Friedman equation (for lambda-cdm) with significant neutrino masses is modified from its simpler form (sum over various densities of c.c., curvature, matter and radiation) to a more complicated one.

What is the form of the Friedman equation (preferably for lambda cdm, or other realistic cosmologies) where neutrino mass is significant?

Given most standard model extensions have some notion of neutrino mass (some heavy), I wondered whether this was a realistic assumption? i.e. are Friedman equations more accurate where neutrino masses are assumed greater than zero?

Comment: When you write "some heavy" are you refering to hypothetical heavy sterile flavors? The energy density of the known flavors is, as I recall, quite small so I expect you would need something exotic to get a big effect.

Comment: @dmckee yes, I suppose that the heavy sterile flavours, and other flavour model building is what I was referring to. I guess I was more so interested in whether (in models not ruled out already, or without significant strain from null results) the neutrino masses have “measurable” implications in cosmology? Say, some modification to the Friedman equations, or radiative corrections to the CvB / background radiation, etc.